# How can I resume a screen that I did not manage to detach?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, terminal-multiplexer

I use the screen [Screen visual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).
To detach a screen I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> but some time a session is closed without detaching it. 
It appears as `(Attached)` on `screen -list`:

```
eduard@eduard-X:~$ screen -list
There are screens on:
        4561.pts-46.eduard-X   (30.03.2015 14:48:51)   (Attached)
        4547.pts-46.eduard-X   (30.03.2015 14:48:33)   (Detached)
        4329.pts-41.eduard-X   (30.03.2015 14:46:28)   (Attached)
        3995.pts-30.eduard-X   (30.03.2015 14:30:01)   (Detached)
```

If i try to restore it, screen responds that there is no screen to resume:

```
eduard@eduard-X:~$ screen -r 4329
There is a screen on:
        4329.pts-41.eduard-X   (30.03.2015 14:46:28)   (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 4329.
```

Can I still resume a screen that I did not detached properly?

Comment: Please copy & paste text instead of using graphics.

Comment: @Celada I added text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, with

```
screen -d -r
```

You can choose *which* screen to detach and reattach as usual by finding the pid (or complete name) with `screen -list`.

```
screen -d -r 12345
```

Answer (score 9):

You should be creating screens with names.

```
$ screen -S foo

$ screen -list
There are screens on:
        16994.foo       (03/30/15 14:05:13)     (Detached)
        20082.q (12/17/14 18:06:44)     (Detached)
        11008.w (11/12/14 10:52:43)     (Detached)
        1199.irc        (11/12/14 01:34:40)     (Detached)
```

Then you can reattach screens with

```
$ screen -dr foo
```

(which will attach to 16994.foo, detaching any other process)
or

```
$ screen -x i
```

(which will attach to 1999.irc, which will SHARE the screen with another process)

Naming screens is important I feel.

Answer (score 6):

Following a comment suggested in the post I used:

```
screen -x <session id>
```

[From the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html):
screen -x

> `-x`   Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode). 
>   Screen refuses to attach from within itself.  **But when cascading
>   multiple screens, loops are not detected; take care.**

Also researching a bit I discovered other uses for this option, [Using screen for remote interaction](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442418-using-screen-for-remote-interaction)  explains that you can connect from multiple terminals, a kind of remote console sharing system,  practically you can see and type remotely in a shared environment.

This can be used when teaching students or setting up things with a colleague.

You can try by connecting to the same screen from two different terminals with the same screen id.(`screen -x 4329`). What you type in one can be seen in the other and vice-versa.